# Within column subtraction iteratively in R

Tags: r, iteration, subtraction

I have the following data:

```
library tidyverse

age_grp <- c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
start <- c(0.420,0.420,0.420,0.420,0.420,0.420,0.420,0.420,0.420,0.420)
change <- c(0.020,0.033,0.029,0.031,0.027,0.032,0.032,0.030,0.027,0.034)
final_outcome <- c(0.400,0.367,0.338,0.307,0.28,0.248,0.216,0.186,0.159,0.125)
my_data <- data.frame(age_grp,start,change,final_outcome)

my_data1 <- my_data %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(age_grp)
```

I would like to subtract the values in the variable `change` from the values in the variable `start` such that it is an iterative decrease from the oldest age group to the youngest. The final values that I am looking to get are in the variable `final_outcome`. For example, starting with `age_grp` 10, I want to subtract 0.20 from 0.420 to get 0.400. Then, I would like to subtract 0.033 from 0.400 to get 0.367 and so forth. I am struggling with how to store those differences. I have made an attempt below, but I don't know how to store the difference to then continue the subtraction forward (or backward, depending on how you look at it). Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
my_data1$attempt <- NA

#calculating the decreases
for(i in 2:nrow(my_data1)) 
   my_data1$attempt[i] <- round(my_data1$start[i] - my_data1$change[i-1], 4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we need the same output as in `final_outcome`

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %>% 
   mutate(attempt = start - cumsum(change)) %>%
   arrange(age_grp)
```

-output

```
#  age_grp start change final_outcome attempt
#1        1  0.42  0.034         0.125   0.125
#2        2  0.42  0.027         0.159   0.159
#3        3  0.42  0.030         0.186   0.186
#4        4  0.42  0.032         0.216   0.216
#5        5  0.42  0.032         0.248   0.248
#6        6  0.42  0.027         0.280   0.280
#7        7  0.42  0.031         0.307   0.307
#8        8  0.42  0.029         0.338   0.338
#9        9  0.42  0.033         0.367   0.367
#10      10  0.42  0.020         0.400   0.400
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my_data$final <- my_data$start - cumsum(my_data$change)
```

Comment: Ohh! I didn't notice yours

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
my_data %>% 
  mutate(attempt = accumulate(change, ~ .x - .y, .init = start[1])[-1])
```

Note: `accumulate` is from the `purrr` library that's part of the `tidyverse`. It also has a `.dir` argument where you can go `"forward"` or `"backward"`.

Or in base `R` using `Reduce`:

```
within(my_data, attempt <- Reduce("-", change, init = start[1], accumulate = T)[-1])
```

`Reduce` has an argument `right` that can also do the computation forwards or backwards.

**Output**

```
   age_grp start change final_outcome attempt
1       10  0.42  0.020         0.400   0.400
2        9  0.42  0.033         0.367   0.367
3        8  0.42  0.029         0.338   0.338
4        7  0.42  0.031         0.307   0.307
5        6  0.42  0.027         0.280   0.280
6        5  0.42  0.032         0.248   0.248
7        4  0.42  0.032         0.216   0.216
8        3  0.42  0.030         0.186   0.186
9        2  0.42  0.027         0.159   0.159
10       1  0.42  0.034         0.125   0.125
```